# running neo4j from a remote machine

Tags: neo4j, remote-access

I have installed and run neo4j 3.3.2 on a Linux machine.

I'm trying to access the console from a remote windows machine from the same network.

I have changed some configs in conf/neo4j-conf like this :

> dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
>   dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
>   dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474
>   dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473

I can now access the browser remotely but I have an error while trying to login:

```
[![WebSocket connection failure. 
Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. 
Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. 
Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. 
If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3"]]
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by accessing the `console` ? Is it the `browser`, `cypher-shell` or something else ?

Comment: yes I meant the browser.I have made progress. I have deactivated the "AlwaysPreTouch" option and all the ones below it. Now I have access to the console but with a problem loggin in. I have updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the **bolt url** : `bolt://0.0.0.0:7687`

This not a valid IP address, you should replace `0.0.0.0` with the IP address of your server.

I suppose that you have also change the value of `dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address` in the configuration with `0.0.0.0` no ?

> # The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or  # it may be the
>   address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This
>   setting may be overridden for  # individual connectors below. 
>   dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=**{PUT HERE YOUR SERVER's IP}**